# HTML5 Canvas - Draw on Canvas, Save Context and Restore it later

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**Requirement:**

Now: Draw on a Canvas, and hit Save (store Canvas state/drawing offline - but NOT as image).
Later: Open up the Canvas with previously saved drawing showing, and continue to draw again.

For drawing we normally use code as follows:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('can');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
...
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
....
```

In order to restore Canvas state later - exporting to Image does not help.
I want to restore the Canvas to it's original state to continue editing the drawing at a later date.

*I guess, the Canvas context has to be exported and stored offline - how?*

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot here is to use a Proxy that will both store the draw commands and perform the drawings.
Since the browser support for Proxy is very bad (only FF as of today), you'll have to build the Proxy yourself, either by using **nosuchmethod**, or by building a new brand new WatchedContext Class out of the Context2D.
I took the last solution (WatchedContext Class) for this short demo :

```
function WatchedContext(hostedCtx) {
  this.commands= [];
  Context2dPrototype = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
  for (var p in Context2dPrototype ) {
    this[p] = function(methodName) {
        return function() {
            this.commands.push(methodName, arguments);
            return Context2dPrototype[methodName].apply(hostedCtx, arguments);
        }      
    }(p);
  }  
  this.replay=function() {
    for (var i=0; i<this.commands.length; i+=2) {
      var com = this.commands[i];
      var args = this.commands[i+1];
      Context2dPrototype[com].apply(hostedCtx, args);
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously you might need some other method (start/stop recording, clear, ...)

Just a small example of use  :

```
var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx=cv.getContext('2d');
var watchedContext=new WatchedContext(ctx);

// do some drawings on the watched context
// --> they are performed also on the real context
watchedContext.beginPath();
watchedContext.moveTo(10, 10);
watchedContext.lineTo(100, 100);
watchedContext.stroke();

// clear context (not using the watched context to avoid recording)
ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,1000);

// replay what was recorded
watchedContext.replay();
```

You can see here :

```
http://jsbin.com/gehixavebe/2/edit?js,output
```

That the replay does work, and the line is re-drawn as a result of replaying the stored commands.

For storing offline you can either store the commands locally using localStorage or store them remotely on a server an use AJAX calls or similar.

Comment: A nice start—well worth +1! To be complete, your code needs to be expanded to account for context properties and for context methods that return values. You could use Object.defineProperty to create getters/setters for the context properties. Most context methods are serialized well with your code, but some context methods will require special handling: .drawImage (serialize the URL), .createLinearGradient, .createRadialGradient, .createPattern, .measureText. And pixel manipulation with .getImageData & .putImageData requires whole subsystem. Still…good work!

Comment: @markE : Thanks for your kind and relevant comments. My intent here is to write a 'short demo', i.e. show a way to solve the issue, then to wait for the O.P.'s comments before (maybe) going further. For a few methods (like createPattern, to take just one example), the above logic would indeed need much rework. But just for some basic drawings, including changing fill/stroke/font, i made some changes to allow access to properties, latest attempt is here : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/b4bfj6uf/