# adding events to context2d draw methods

Tags: events, html5-canvas, dart, draw

I have tried many different "On" events and none of them seem to support what I'm looking for. is there a way to listen to when the canvas is drawn to? or even context is accessed or received? really anything that remotely resembles a change to the imagedata would be great...

Comment: There's no such 'OnChange' event, but you can inject the Context2D to have a flag set whenever a change is made to the content (or an event raised). Just to illustrate how injection could work, you might have a look to this answer of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26561295/856501

Comment: that looks like a kind of "inheritance" way of doing it, but that would require that someone use my version of canvas (one that is tracking and invalidating on draw commands) which isn't a terribly bad way of doing it, I'm just wondering if there is any other way of doing such a thing

Comment: Anyway since it's not built-in you'll have to provide specific code. Only other way i see is to compare the current imageData to a saved one, on rAF or less frequently.

Comment: yeah I suppose thats making a literal listenner, I try to stay away from those as much as possible (events are NOT fast or Efficient) Thanks for the answer... you should probably post it as one...