# Is it possible to save the canvas context, not the image, to a file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a drawing app using HTML5 canvas for browsers. In the app, I want to save the drawing in the middle of production and close the browser, and open the app later and resume the work.  Is that possible?

toDataURL() is not for this purpose because it outputs an image, not the canvas' context.  save()/restore() functions don't seem to be able to export/import files.

Comment: You would have to save all the property changes in an object, that you would store e.g as JSON, and then iterate this object to perform again all these property changes. Yes doable, but there are so many ways this can be done, which so highly depends on your application and the way you handle user inputs, that it wouldn't make too much sense to try to write you an off-the-box solution.

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560283/html5-canvas-draw-on-canvas-save-context-and-restore-it-later

Comment: You could probably `class SerializableCanvasRenderingContext2D extends CanvasRenderingContext2D {...}` and override all the methods you want to intercept in order to create export / import functionality